# Get recently added / changed item in a Select list (via jQuery or Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I have a `multiple` `select` using the [`chosen`](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) jquery plugin. I'm looking at the `change` event to find the recently added item.

Since I couldn't find any easy way to get the recently added item, I'm looking at the latest value in the array.

Since, the value array is being sorted automatically. I'm not sure how I can find the recently added item. Any thoughts / ideas would be greatly appreciated.

The change event handler looks like this -

```
 $('#chosenSelect').chosen().change(function() {
          var lastVal = $('#chosenSelect').val()[$('#chosenSelect').val().length - 1];
          console.log(lastVal);
 });
```

I'm using jQuery 2.0.3 alongside Angular JS (Any suggestions to get the recently added item via Angular JS would help too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Jquery to edit the DOM without using an AngularJS directive, it is not a good practice to do so when using AngularJS, I recommend you to use the [AngularUI's Select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) directive, using this directive you can pass the values to the multi select using the ng-model attribute, and use [$scope.$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch) to track the last added values.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not very elegant but you can try this:

```
$('#chosenSelect').chosen().change(function() {
                         //Get the click event on the dropdown li elements
                         $(".chosen-drop li").on("click", function()
                            {
                                //This is the array index of the chosen value
                                var index = $(this).attr("data-option-array-index");
                                var lastText = '';
                                var lastVal= '';
                                //Then get the text value of the chosen li element              
                                $(".chosen-drop li").each(function()
                                    {
                                        if($(this).attr("data-option-array-index")==index)
                                            {
                                                lastText = $(this).text();
                                            }
                                    })
                                //Then find the option with the same text value in the original select          
                                $("#chosenSelect option").each(function()
                                    {
                                        if($(this).text()==lastText)
                                            {
                                                lastVal = $(this).val();
                                            }
                                    })

                                console.log(lastVal);
                            })
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $scope.$watch is a good way to go. Here is what I did -

**HTML**

```
<select id="chosenSelect" ng-model="chosenSelectedItem" name="property" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select a property">
```

**Javascript**

```
var recentProperty;

$scope.$watch('chosenSelectedItem', function (newVal, oldVal) {
       if(newVal)
       {
          $.each(newVal, function(index, item){
             if($.inArray(item, oldVal) == -1)
             {
                recentProperty = item;
                return false;
             }
          });
          console.log(recentProperty);
       }
});
```